How can I have the Listener Client/Sender Client to connect through a NGINX reverse proxy to the Azure Relay Service Hybrid Connection?
I want to configure a NGINX reverse proxy in between the azure hybrid connection relay service and the listener client.
After the initial "listen" websocket connection to the service (listener control channel connection), we receive a dynamic "accept" websocket address from the service using the control channel connection, which is then used by the listener to communicate with the sender.
How do I configure the listener client to pass through the nginx reverse proxy server ?
As reverse proxy in front of listener would have been complicated, I tried to have the sender client messages go through a reverse proxy to the azure relay service. But in this case also, the azure service is sending a TCP RST packet as soon as application data is sent from the reverse proxy.
Please find the below code helpful:
require("dotenv").config();
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; // Disables certificate verification

const WebSocket = require("hyco-ws");
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

const ns = process.env.RelayNamespace;
const path = process.env.HybridConnectionName;
const keyrule = process.env.SASKeyName;
const key = process.env.SASKeyValue;

const proxiedAddress = WebSocket.createRelaySendUri("localhost", path);
console.log("Proxied URL: ");
console.log(proxiedAddress);

const uri = WebSocket.createRelaySendUri(ns, path);
const token = WebSocket.createRelayToken(uri, keyrule, key);

console.log("Actual URL: ");
console.log(uri);

console.log("Token: ");
console.log(token);

WebSocket.relayedConnect(proxiedAddress, token, function (wss) {
  readline.on("line", (input) => {
    wss.send(input, null);
  });

  console.log("Started client interval.");
  wss.on("close", function () {
    console.log("stopping client interval");
    process.exit();
  });
});


Also, find the following nginx configuration helpful:
http {
    upstream relayservice {
        server revproxy.servicebus.windows.net:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate cert/localhost.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key cert/localhost.key;

        location ~ ^/(\$hc.*)$ {
            proxy_read_timeout 300s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
            proxy_pass https://relayservice/$1$is_args$args;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        }
    }
}

events {}

How do I configure the senderclient to pass through the nginx reverse proxy server ?
Find the below wireshark snapshot image helpful.

Note:
The Hybrid Connections service endpoint is referred to as the "service".
The programs on both sides of a connection are called "clients," since they're clients to the service. The client that waits for and accepts connections is the "listener," or is said to be in the "listener role." The client that initiates a new connection towards a listener via the service is called the "sender," or is in the "sender role."

please share the code /think you tried. Please read How to Ask, along with how to create a minimal reproducible example.

@Sampath As reverse proxy in front of listener would have been complicated, I tried to have the sender client messages go through a reverse proxy to the azure relay service.

. If your web server is dropping connections with a TCP reset under high load, investigate potential causes and solutions on Server Fault. For configuring Nginx SSL/TLS passthrough with TCP load balancing, refer to the detailed guide on nixCraft.

To address Azure Relay exceptions, consult the Azure Relay documentation. If your web server is dropping connections with a TCP reset under high load, investigate potential causes and solutions on Server Fault. For configuring Nginx SSL/TLS passthrough with TCP load balancing, refer to the detailed guide on nixCraft.
The below JavaScript code appears to set up a WebSocket client using the hyco-ws library and generates a relay token using WebSocket.createRelayToken.
const WebSocket = require("hyco-ws");
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

const ns = "sampath.servicebus.windows.net";
const path = "sampujari";
const keyrule = "sharedAccessKeyName";
const key = "Key";

const uri = `wss://${ns}:443/$hc/${path}`;
const token = WebSocket.createRelayToken(uri, keyrule, key);

console.log("WebSocket URL: ", uri);
console.log("Token: ", token);

WebSocket.relayedConnect(
  uri,
  token,
  function (wss) {
    readline.on("line", (input) => {
      wss.send(input, null);
    });

    console.log("Started client interval.");

    wss.on("message", function (data, flags) {
      console.log("Received: ", data);
    });

    wss.on("close", function () {
      console.log("WebSocket connection closed.");
      process.exit();
    });
  },
  function (err) {
    console.error("Error connecting to WebSocket:", err);
  }
);


The code below sets up a WebSocket client to connect to a WebSocket server to generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token using proxiedAddress
nginx.conf.json:
proxy_pass https://sampath7888.servicebus.windows.net/sampujari;


Refer to authentication and authorization of  Azure Relay

const WebSocket = require("hyco-ws");
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
const crypto = require('crypto');
const moment = require('moment');

const proxiedAddress = "http://localhost:8080/ws";
const ns = "sampath7888.servicebus.windows.net";
const path = "sampujari";
const keyrule = " ";
const key = " ";

// Function to generate SAS token
function generateSasToken(namespace, path, keyRule, key) {
    const uri = encodeURIComponent(`https://${namespace}/${path}`);
    const expiry = moment().add(1, 'days').unix(); // Token expires in 1 day

    const stringToSign = `${uri}\n${expiry}`;
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(key, 'base64'));
    hmac.update(stringToSign);
    const signature = encodeURIComponent(hmac.digest('base64'));

    return `SharedAccessSignature sr=${uri}&sig=${signature}&se=${expiry}&skn=${keyRule}`;
}

// Generate SAS token
const uri = WebSocket.createRelaySendUri(ns, path);
const token = generateSasToken(ns, path, keyrule, key);

console.log("Proxied URL: ", proxiedAddress);
console.log("WebSocket URL: ", uri);
console.log("Token: ", token);

WebSocket.relayedConnect(
  proxiedAddress,
  token,
  function (wss) {
    readline.on("line", (input) => {
      wss.send(input, null);
    });

    console.log("Started client interval.");

    wss.on("message", function (data, flags) {
      console.log("Received: ", data);
    });

    wss.on("close", function () {
      console.log("WebSocket connection closed.");
      process.exit();
    });

    wss.on("error", function (error) {
      console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
     
    });
  },
  function (err) {
    console.error("Error connecting to WebSocket:", err);
    
  }
);






The proxy pass in the above case will work for https connections, but not for websocket connection. Nginx Access log: 192.168.65.1 - - [04/Apr/2024:06:10:52 +0000] "GET /ws HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-" and unexpected server response (400)
